# TS compilation - "noImplicitAny" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

I have the code

```
let z;
z = 50;
z = 'z';
```

and my tsconfig.json is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

But what the hell it is that there's no exceptions throgh compiling to js?

Best Regards,
Crova

Answer (score 5):

Because `z` is never typed as `any`. The type of `z` is simply inferred based on what you assign to it.

From the [release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference):

> With TypeScript 2.1, instead of just choosing any, TypeScript will
>   infer types based on what you end up assigning later on.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> let x;
>
> // You can still assign anything you want to 'x'.
> x = () => 42;
>
> // After that last assignment, TypeScript 2.1 knows that 'x' has type '() => number'.
> let y = x();
>
> // Thanks to that, it will now tell you that you can't add a number to a function!
> console.log(x + y);
> //          ~~~~~
> // Error! Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '() => number' and 'number'.
>
> // TypeScript still allows you to assign anything you want to 'x'.
> x = "Hello world!";
>
> // But now it also knows that 'x' is a 'string'!
> x.toLowerCase();
> ```

So in your case:

```
let z;
z = 50;
let y = z * 10; // `z` is number here. No error
z = 'z';
z.replace("z", "")// `z` is string here. No error
```

Comment: Is there a flag that disallows this behaviour?

Comment: None as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

`noImplicitAny` literally means:

> Trigger an error if TypeScript uses 'any' whenever it can't infer a
>   type

In your case above at any point of your code compiler easily infer what is the type of `z`. And therefore it can check that the appropriate methods/props you are calling on `z` is allowed or not.

Comment: In what scenario would --noImplicitAny do at least something?